# How to get value from other table and show in datatables

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, datatables

**This is the view of my index now , as u can see that date add by me , I want to show the due date beside the gylight.**

Picture A
[image]

**This is the view of my index with the coding i try to join the `guanyins` table to find due date, but it just show out the 2 members have buy the lights. Actually I want to do is show out all the list of members. As above Picture A.**

Picture B
[image]

**This is my member's `light` table**

0 mean no light, 1 mean light on

```
|id| sx_ID | gylight| qflight | palight |
-----------------------------------------
|1 |SX00001|    0   |    0    |    0    |
|2 |SX00002|    1   |    0    |    0    |
|3 |SX00003|    0   |    0    |    0    |
|4 |SX00004|    1   |    0    |    0    |
-----------------------------------------
```

**This is my `guanyins` table**

```
|gy_id| gy_sx_ID | gylight_number| gylight_sDate | gylight_eDate |
-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1  |  SX00002 |    A1-1       |   2020-11-13  |   2021-11-13  |
|  2  |  SX00002 |    A1-17      |   2020-11-11  |   2020-11-16  |
|  3  |  SX00004 |    A1-2       |   2020-11-11  |   2020-11-16  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**This is the index controller I try to call out the data with `join` function.**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    
    if($request->header('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'){
        $column = array(
            'sx_ID',
            'sx_Cname',
            'sx_Ename',
            'sx_NRIC',
            'sx_oldIC',
            'sx_dob',
            'sx_gender',
            'sx_phone',
            'sx_address',
        );

        

        $filter = array();
        if($request->order) {
            $filter['orderByField'] = $column[$request->order[0]['column']];
            $filter['orderBy'] = $request->order[0]['dir'];
        }

        if($request->search) {
            $filter['search'] = $request->search['value'];
            
        }

       
        $filter_row =  Light::select('*')
                              ->applyFilter($filter)
                              ->count();

        $sxlight = Light::rightJoin('guanyins', function($join) {
                             $join->on('guanyins.sx_ID','=', 'lights.sx_ID');
                          })
                          ->select('*')
                          ->offset($request->get('start'))
                          ->limit($request->get('length'))
                          ->applyFilter($filter)
                          ->get();
        $data = [];
        
        foreach($sxlight as $sxlight){         
            
            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array[] = $sxlight->sx_ID;
            $sub_array[] = $sxlight->sx_Cname .'<br>'. 
                           $sxlight->sx_Ename .'<br>'. 
                           $sxlight->sx_NRIC .'<br>'. 
                           $sxlight->sx_oldIC.'<br>'. 
                           $sxlight->sx_phone.'<br><br>'. 
                           str_replace( "," , "<br>",  $sxlight->sx_address);
            
            $sub_array[] = $sxlight->light.'('.$sxlight->gylight_eDate .')';


            $sub_array[] = '<a type="button" href="'. route('admin.light.view', ['light' => $sxlight->id]) .'" class="btn btn-primary radius">'.
                           '查看'.
                           '</a>';
            $data[] = $sub_array;
        }
        return response()->json([
            'draw' => $request->draw,
            'recordsTotal' => Light::count(),
            'recordsFiltered' => $filter_row,
            'data' => $data,
            'request' => $filter,
        ]);
    }

       $sxlight = Light::orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get(); 

       return view('admin.light.index',[
               'sxlight' => $sxlight,
       ]);
}
```

**This is my model**

```
  class Light extends Model
{   
  protected $fillable = ['sx_street1', 'sx_street2', 'sx_postcode', 'sx_city', 'sx_state', 'sx_country'];
  protected $guarded=[];
  protected $table = 'lights';


  public function guanyins()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Guanyin::class, 'sx_ID','sx_ID');
  }

  public function gyedate()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Guanyin::class ,'sx_ID','gylight_eDate');
  }

  public function getLightAttribute()
  {
    $light = "";
    if($this->gylight){
        $light .= "gylight";
    }
    if($this->qflight){
        $light .="<br><br>qflight";
    }
    if($this->palight){
        $light .="<br><br>palight";
    }
    return $light;
  }

  public function getAgeAttribute()
  {
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['sx_dob'])->age;
  }


  public function scopeWhereOrder($query, $orderByField, $orderBy)
  {
    $field = explode('.', $orderByField);
    if(count($field) != 1){
        $query->with([$field[0] => function($query) use ($field, $orderBy){
            $query->orderBy($field[1], $orderBy);
        }]);
    }else{
        $query->orderBy($orderByField, $orderBy);
    }
  }

  public function scopeApplyFilter($query, array $filters)
  {
    $filters = collect($filters);
    
    if($filters->get('search')){
        $search = $filters->get('search');
        $query->where('sx_ID','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
              ->orWhere('sx_Cname','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
              ->orWhere('sx_Ename','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
              ->orWhere('sx_NRIC','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
              ->orWhere('sx_oldIC','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
              ->orWhere('sx_phone','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
    }

    $field = $filters->get('orderbyField') ? $filters->get('orderByField') : 'id';
    $orderBy = $filters->get('orderBy') ? $filters->get('orderBy') : 'desc';
    $query->whereOrder($field, $orderBy);
  }
}
```

**New Updated 16/11/2020**

Picture C

[image]

Comment: why are you not using [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) for that

Comment: @bhucho U mean like this ?
`public function gyedate()
  {

    return $this->hasMany(Guanyin::class, 'sx_ID','gylight_eDate');

  }`  in my model

Comment: looks ok to me, inform if you have any error

Comment: @bhucho  I have updated the coding and picture, seen like my join function have some problem , because it just show out the list of member who had bought the light. Actually I want to show is all the `light` member in a table no matter the member buy a light or not

Comment: In comparison in join statement you want all members from the light table then you can use rightJoin() it will perform a right join & includes all the values from the right of comparison

Comment: @bhucho I try to `rightJoin()` it , but it showing the data was sort by the `guanyins`  table,  I have updated the code

Comment: can you try for `leftJoin()` then as you are joining something like, `$sxlight = Light::leftJoin('guanyins AS gs', function($join) { $join->on('gs.sx_ID','=', 'lights.sx_ID'); })`

Comment: nice that it got solved, even I was getting confused, I guess I will have to brush up my sql skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leftJoin()` solved it

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    
    if($request->header('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'){
        $column = array(
            'sx_ID',
            'sx_Cname',
            'sx_Ename',
            'sx_NRIC',
            'sx_oldIC',
            'sx_dob',
            'sx_gender',
            'sx_phone',
            'sx_address',
        );

        

        $filter = array();
        if($request->order) {
            $filter['orderByField'] = $column[$request->order[0]['column']];
            $filter['orderBy'] = $request->order[0]['dir'];
        }

        if($request->search) {
            $filter['search'] = $request->search['value'];
            
        }

       
        $filter_row =  Light::select('*')
                              ->applyFilter($filter)
                              ->count();

        $sxlight = Light::leftJoin('guanyins AS gs', function($join) {
                            $join->on('gs.gy_sx_ID','=', 'lights.sx_ID')
                                 ->where('gs.gylight_eDate','>', Carbon::now());
                          })
                          ->select('*')
                          ->groupBy('sx_ID')
                          ->offset($request->get('start'))
                          ->limit($request->get('length'))
                          ->applyFilter($filter)
                          ->get();
        $data = [];
        
        foreach($sxlight as $sxlight){         
            
            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array[] = $sxlight->sx_ID;
            $sub_array[] = $sxlight->sx_Cname .'<br>'. 
                           $sxlight->sx_Ename .'<br>'. 
                           $sxlight->sx_NRIC .'<br>'. 
                           $sxlight->sx_oldIC.'<br>'. 
                           $sxlight->sx_phone.'<br><br>'. 
                           str_replace( "," , "<br>",  $sxlight->sx_address);
            
            if($sxlight->light)
            {
                $sub_array[] = $sxlight->light.'('.$sxlight->gyedate .')';
            }
            else
            {
                $sub_array[] = null;
            }


            $sub_array[] = '<a type="button" href="'. route('admin.light.view', ['light' => $sxlight->id]) .'" class="btn btn-primary radius">'.
                           '查看'.
                           '</a>';
            $data[] = $sub_array;
        }
        return response()->json([
            'draw' => $request->draw,
            'recordsTotal' => Light::count(),
            'recordsFiltered' => $filter_row,
            'data' => $data,
            'request' => $filter,
        ]);
    }

       $sxlight = Light::orderBy('lights.id', 'desc')
                ->get(); 

       return view('admin.light.index',[
               'sxlight' => $sxlight,
       ]);
}
```